# Docker + Rails6系 + TailwindCSSバージョン3で、TailwindCSSのスタイルの反映がうまくいかない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker-compose, tailwindcss

### 概要

Docker + Rails6系 + TailwindCSSバージョン3でアプリを作成しているのですが、TailwindCSSのスタイルの反映がうまくいかないので相談させてください。

### 実現したいこと

index.html.erbにて、新しいTailwindのクラスを追加した際に即時スタイルを反映したい。

### 発生している問題

例えば、現在のindex.html.erbが以下のソースコードの場合、

```
# index.html.erb

<h1 class="text-3xl font-bold underline text-orange-700">
  Hello world!
</h1>

<p class="text-orange-200">The quick brown fox...</p>
<p class="text-purple-600">i have a dream</p>
```

localhost:3000を開くと以下のように、「i have a dream」にtext-purple-600が反映されていません。リロードをしたとしても、反映されません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

しかし、なぜかtailwind.config.jsファイルのcontentの箇所を以下の状態から、

```
# tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
  content: ["./app/**/*.{html,js,erb,rb}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

以下の状態にすると

```
# tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
  content: ["./app/**/**/*.{html,js,erb,rb}"], 
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

以下の画像のようにスタイルが反映されます。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

また、この状態でindex.html.erbの一番下に新しくcolor green

を追加すると、

```
# index.html.erb

<h1 class="text-3xl font-bold underline text-orange-700">
  Hello world!
</h1>

<p class="text-orange-200">The quick brown fox...</p>
<p class="text-purple-600">i have a dream</p>
<p class="text-green-600">color green</p>
```

以下のようにスタイルは反映されません。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ここからtailwind.config.jsファイルのcontentの状態を、以下のように一番はじめの状態に戻してリロードすると、

```
# tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
  content: ["./app/**/*.{html,js,erb,rb}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

スタイルが反映されます。

なぜtailwind.config.jsファイルのcontentの状態を毎回修正したり、元に戻したりしないとスタイルが反映されないのでしょうか？

### 関連ファイルの状態

その他関連ファイルは以下のようになっています。

```
# application.html.erb

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Myapp</title>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= csp_meta_tag %>

  <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
</head>

<body>
  <%= yield %>
</body>

</html>
app/javascript/stylesheets/application.css
```

```
# app/javascript/stylesheets/application.css

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

```
# app/javascript/packs/application.js

// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.

require("@rails/ujs").start();
require("turbolinks").start();
require("@rails/activestorage").start();
require("channels");
import "../stylesheets/application.css";

// Uncomment to copy all static images under ../images to the output folder and reference
// them with the image_pack_tag helper in views (e.g <%= image_pack_tag 'rails.png' %>)
// or the `imagePath` JavaScript helper below.
//
// const images = require.context('../images', true)
// const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)
```

```
# postcss.config.js

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require("postcss-import"),
    require("postcss-flexbugs-fixes"),
    require("tailwindcss")("./app/javascript/stylesheets/tailwind.config.js"),
    require("autoprefixer"),
    require("postcss-preset-env")({
      autoprefixer: {
        flexbox: "no-2009",
      },
      stage: 3,
    }),
  ],
};
```

```
# package.json

{
  "name": "myapp",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "^5.4.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^9",
    "postcss": "^8.4.13",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.24",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@webpack-cli/serve": "^1.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~3"
  }
}
```

```
# docker-compose.yml

version: "3"
services:
  webpack:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
      - gem_data:/usr/local/bundle
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
      RAILS_ENV: development
      WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_HOST: 0.0.0.0
    command: bash -c "bin/webpack-dev-server"
    ports:
      - '3035:3035'
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
        - "4306:3306"
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid &&  bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
      - gem_data:/usr/local/bundle
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_HOST: webpack
volumes:
  mysql_data:
  gem_data:
```

```
# app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, or any plugin's
 * vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

```
# webpacker.yml

# Note: You must restart bin/webpack-dev-server for changes to take effect

default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  check_yarn_integrity: false
  webpack_compile_output: true

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  resolved_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: false

  static_assets_extensions:
    - .jpg
    - .jpeg
    - .png
    - .gif
    - .tiff
    - .ico
    - .svg
    - .eot
    - .otf
    - .ttf
    - .woff
    - .woff2

  extensions:
    - .mjs
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Verifies that correct packages and versions are installed by inspecting package.json, yarn.lock, and node_modules
  check_yarn_integrity: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    pretty: false
    headers:
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    watch_options:
      ignored: "**/node_modules/**"

test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: true

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

Answer (score 0):

`tailwindcss-rails`というgemをご使用でしょうか？
もし使っていたら、いつも`rails s`で起動するところを`./bin/dev`で起動するようにすると正常に動作するかもしれません

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！gemは使用していません。
npmで入れています。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
tailwindcssがhtmlの変更を検知して自動でcssをリビルドするのはwatchモードと呼ばれますが、これは不具合の塊です。ご質問のように変更をスルーする症状が多発します。
なので対処法としてはwatchモードを使用せず、htmlを変更したら「tailwindcss -i ./src/style.css -o ./dist/style.css」のようなビルドコマンドをいちいち実行するようにWebpackerで設定するのが確実だと思います。または、開発中だけCDN版を利用するなどでも良いです。
申し訳ないのですが私はこの環境を使っていないので具体的なコードを出せません。でもできるはずです。ご健闘をお祈りします。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！「不具合の塊」という情報が知れただけでかなり救われた気持ちになれました！数日前にバージョン2を入れ直し、htmlにtailwindのスタイルを当てたら→画面をリロードする、というやり方で今は落ち着きました。今後またバージョン3にはトライしたいので、その際は上記のコマンドをpackage.jsonに書き込んで実行したいと思います。この度はご回答いただきありがとうございました！